# Create DXGI Swapchain for SDL2 window

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, sdl, dxgi

I'm trying to create a DXGI swapchain for a window created by SDL2 (v2.0.18), but every time I call the `IDXGIFactory5::CreateSwapChainForHwnd` method, I get the `E_INVALIDARG` error.

### Steps I'm Following

First, I create the SDL window.

Then I go about creating the swapchain, following these steps:

1. Determine the index of the adapter containing the window
2. Create a D3D11Device
3. Create a DXGI swapchain using said device via the CreateSwapChainForHwnd method, passing the underlying HWND handle in the SDL_Window structure

I'll now share the code I'm using to accomplish these steps

#### Creating the SDL window

```
int posX = 0, int posY = 0, int width = 1920, int height = 1080;

// Init video subsystem
if (SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION,
                "SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) failed: %s",
                SDL_GetError());
        return false;
}

window = SDL_CreateWindow("H264 HW Decoding with D3D11 Rendering to SDL window",
        posX,
        posY,
        width,
        height,
        SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI
);

if (!window) {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION,
                "SDL_CreateWindow() failed: %s",
                SDL_GetError());

        SDL_QuitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
}
```

#### Determine the index of the adapter containing the window

```
if (!SDL_DXGIGetOutputInfo(SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex(params->window),
    &adapterIndex, &outputIndex))
{
    SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION,
        "SDL_DXGIGetOutputInfo() failed: %s",
        SDL_GetError());
    return false;
}
```

#### Create a D3D11Device

```
IDXGIFactory5* Factory = nullptr;
bool success = false;
IDXGIAdapter1* adapter = nullptr;
HRESULT hr;

hr = CreateDXGIFactory2(DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG ,__uuidof(IDXGIFactory5), (void**)&Factory);
assert(!FAILED(hr));

hr = Factory->EnumAdapters1(adapterIndex, &adapter);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION,
        "IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters1() failed: %x",
        hr);
    goto Exit;
}

hr = adapter->GetDesc1(&adapterDesc);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION,
        "IDXGIAdapter::GetDesc() failed: %x",
        hr);
    goto Exit;
}

if (adapterDesc.Flags & DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_SOFTWARE)
{
    // Skip the WARP device. We know it will fail.
    goto Exit;
}

hr = D3D11CreateDevice(adapter,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN,
    nullptr,
    D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT,
    nullptr,
    0,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &Device,
    nullptr,
    &DeviceContext);
```

#### Create a DXGI swapchain using said device via the CreateSwapChainForHwnd method, passing the underlying HWND handle in the SDL_Window structure

```
// Fill the swapchain description structure
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = {0};
swapChainDesc.Stereo = FALSE;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;
swapChainDesc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_UNSPECIFIED;
swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 5;
// Use the current window size as the swapchain size
SDL_GetWindowSize(window, (int*)&swapChainDesc.Width, (int*)&swapChainDesc.Height);
swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;

// Get the HWND from SDL
SDL_SysWMinfo info;
SDL_VERSION(&info.version);
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(params->window, &info);
SDL_assert(info.subsystem == SDL_SYSWWINDOWS);
assert(IsWindow(info.info.win.window));

// Create the swapchain and associate it to the SDL window
IDXGISwapChain1* swapChain;
hr = Factory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(Device,
    info.info.win.window,
    &swapChainDesc,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    &swapChain);
```

### Debug Layer Output

I've turned the DXGI debug layer on, and this is the output from it

```
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Context: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3F7978990, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097225: CREATE_CONTEXT]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3DDeviceContextState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3F7996B50, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #3145735: CREATE_DEVICECONTEXTSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11BlendState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3F79963A0, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097270: CREATE_BLENDSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11DepthStencilState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3F79965E0, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097273: CREATE_DEPTHSTENCILSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11RasterizerState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3F79A1F00, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097276: CREATE_RASTERIZERSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Sampler: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3F79A2140, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097267: CREATE_SAMPLER]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Query: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3F79A2380, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097279: CREATE_QUERY]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Fence: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3F79A2600, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #3146250: CREATE_FENCE]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Fence: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3F79A2600 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #3146252: DESTROY_FENCE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA034FF0, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097234: CREATE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA035430, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097234: CREATE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA035870, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097234: CREATE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA035CB0, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097234: CREATE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA0360F0, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097234: CREATE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA0870F0, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097234: CREATE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA08B540, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097234: CREATE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA08B980, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097234: CREATE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA08C1D0, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097234: CREATE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA08C610, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097234: CREATE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Fence: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA04E870, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #3146250: CREATE_FENCE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Fence: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA090370, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #3146250: CREATE_FENCE]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Fence: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA04E870 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #3146252: DESTROY_FENCE]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Fence: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA090370 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #3146252: DESTROY_FENCE]
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD803AFE7C in decode_video_ffmpeg_example.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000079E9AFEF88.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD803AFE7C in decode_video_ffmpeg_example.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000079E9AFF000.
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA034FF0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097236: DESTROY_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA035430 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097236: DESTROY_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA035870 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097236: DESTROY_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA035CB0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097236: DESTROY_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x000001B3FA0360F0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097236: DESTROY_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Texture2D: Name="DXGI cross-adapter flip proxy (dGPU opened)", Addr=0x000001B3FA0870F0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097236: DESTROY_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Texture2D: Name="DXGI cross-adapter flip proxy (dGPU opened)", Addr=0x000001B3FA08B540 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097236: DESTROY_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Texture2D: Name="DXGI cross-adapter flip proxy (dGPU opened)", Addr=0x000001B3FA08B980 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097236: DESTROY_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Texture2D: Name="DXGI cross-adapter flip proxy (dGPU opened)", Addr=0x000001B3FA08C1D0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097236: DESTROY_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Texture2D: Name="DXGI cross-adapter flip proxy (dGPU opened)", Addr=0x000001B3FA08C610 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097236: DESTROY_TEXTURE2D]
```

The DirectX11 debug layer output is juts the following message

```
E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid.
```

### Things I've already tried

1. Using different versions of the DXGI factory (`IDXGIFactory2` and `IDXGIFactory3`)
2. Creating different types of `D3D11Device` (like `D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE` and `D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE`)
3. Instead of calling `SDL_CreateWindow`, creating a native window with these style flags `WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX`, and then creating the SDL window using the `SDL_CreateWindowFrom` function
4. Following [this](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/blob/main/Direct3D11Tutorials/Tutorial01/Tutorial01.cpp) tutorial from Microsoft, where the `CreateSwapchainForHwnd` is used. This program gives me no problems; the method executes successfully and the window is displayed correctly
5. Changing the values set in the `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1` structure (output format, swap effect, scaling, buffer count, window size)

### My Environment

```
OS: Windows 11
Processor: AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX with Radeon Graphics
Graphic Adapters: NVIDIA RTX3060 Laptop GPU; AMD Radeon Graphics (integrated)
```

Comment: Do you have a fully reproducing sample instead of sparse pieces of code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem. It had nothing to do with SDL or the parameters of the swapchain.

There was an old version of `dxgi.dll` file in the same directory as the compiled project. This DLL was not compatible with my sample project. After removing this file the code executed correctly. Embarrassing...